# replace string with a string java

Tags: java, regex, encoding

I have a weird problem .

I am calling a web service in my application and the response sometimes printed like this in the console `"\n"` now i want to is to  replace it with an empty brackets so it will be printed like this `""`

so what i have tried

```
String serverResponse = Util.callService(.....);
System.out.println(serverResponse.replace("\"\\n\"","\"\"");
```

but the output still prints `"\n"` not `""`

when i hard code the string  , it works

for example

```
String str = ""\"\\n\""; // equals to "\n" in console 
 System.out.println(serverResponse.replace("\"\\n\"","\"\""); //prints ""
```

what is the problem ? is it encoding thing ? why the first code does not work with server response ??

Note: I have no control over the web service.

Comment: Check the hex from the response:
for( char c : response.toCharArray() )
    System.out.print( Integer.toHexString( c ) + " " ); This should print 22 5c 6e 22

Comment: you are right it print 22 5c 6e 22 . what is the problem ?? how could i replace the string

Comment: What about the static "\"\\n\"" string, does it return the same characters? (they shouldn't be but you never know)

Comment: If the two strings' char[]s are exactly equal than the behavior won't be different.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it it requires 4 back slash, not two:

```
String serverResponse = Util.callService(.....);
System.out.println(serverResponse.replace("\"\\\\n\"","\"\"");
```